# d3js v4: Performance problems using d3js on real time line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, svg, charts

I'm trying to make a chart software using d3.js and socket.io for measurement data. The measurement data are coming in real time via socket.io and must be drawn in the chart. I am drawing simple line chart with up to 20 different series for different measurement data. I have 50 data points every second, so after a while I have a lot of data points to draw, ( in one hour: 180000) I have to show all the chart data from the very beginning of measurement.

It all works fine, I can zoom in and out, but the performance is going down if more and more data points are arriving.

If new data set arrive, I append it to the data I already have, remove the chart, redraw the chart and rescale the chart and the axis. I am rendering on SVG. After a while the performance breaks down.

Even if I try to reduce the data to be drawn, the performance after a while is still bad.

How can I improve the performance ? Could crossfilter help me ? Is the idea of drawing the whole chart every millisecond completely new good ?

I heard that rendering on SVG is not so performed then on canvas. Is that right ?

Comment: filter the data, you can't possibly see or want so much data to be drawn on the screen. If the user zooms in re-filter it.

Comment: To extend on Robert's comment, create different data sets for different views, if zoomed out use a data set where each data point  is a generalised representation of many, eg min,max, and mean for 100 or more points. When zoomed in only present data within the viewable range. Exploit memory as it is cheaper than CPU cycles and having 10 versions of the same data will take up more RAM but that you are not running out of and it will give you much better performance.

Comment: You can't possibly render 180,000 points on screen, there just aren't enough pixels! How about down-sampling the data? There's a component here that can help: https://d3fc.io/api/sample-api.html

Comment: Thanx for all the inspirations. I will try the approach to reduce data by down-sampling it.